# How data is stored on AWS DynamoDB internally? Encrypted or plain text?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

We can able to see the data stored in AWS DynamoDB using clients. But how the data is being stored on DynamoDb? Is encrypted format or plain text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DynamoDB stores the data as plain text (i.e. without encryption).

If you encrypt and store the data, the Query or Scan on the attribute may not be possible.

[Server side encryption not available](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=603690)

[Java DynamoDB encryption library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-dynamodb-encryption-java)

`@DoNotEncrypt` - Annotation can be used on the mapper file to not encrypt the attribute data.

`@DoNotTouch` - Not encrypted nor signed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-dynamodb-encryption-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
```